# Salesforce Partner WSDL Java Client

Tags: soap-api, java, wsdl

I'm creating a Java WS Client (Salesforce Partner WSDL) and following the Salesforce "Setting Up Your Java Developer Environment" document.   It recommends installing the Web Services Connector (WSDL-Based APIs) and generate Java Stub Files by using this command

```
java –classpath path to WSC jar/WSC jar filename
com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc path to WSDL/WSDL filename path to
output stub jar and filename
```

Is this the correct way to create the web client or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

There are fairly detailed examples on getting up and running from Java in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

In particular, you want:

- [Step 2: Generate or Obtain the Web Service WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_generate_wsdl.htm)
- [Step 3: Import the WSDL File Into Your Development Platform](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_import_wsdl.htm)
- [Step 4: Walk Through the Sample Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_walk_through_code.htm)

These show importing your resulting jar for the WSDL and establishing a session.

See also:

1. [Setting Up Your Java Developer Environment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_overview.htm)
2. Trailhead - [API Basics - Use SOAP API](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_soap)

Comment: Thanks Daniel!   I actually got this working.  Had to create the java stub 
 file for the partner wsdl and that did the trick!(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_overview.htm) 

Although, one item in the instruction need to be careful about; copy the tools.jar to the location of you wsdl; pointing the JDK folder didn't work

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it sorted.